# Check for process existing

Tags: c++, mfc, process

I write a code and using MFC.
I want to check if process exists or not.

for example:

```
if (myProcess.exe exists)
  do something
else
  do something else
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this line right after including Psapi.h:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib")
```

try also this one:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use named mutex:

At the beginning of program:

```
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, "Your program name");
if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
{
    // Process already running.
    CloseHandle(hMutex);
}
else
{
    // No process running.
}
```

At the end of program:

```
if (hMutex)
{
    CloseHandle(hMutex);
    hMutex = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must enumerate the processes

e.g.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.
I did it but got an error: "the procedure entry point k32 enumprocesses could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll". How Can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The process can store its process ID in a file. On normal exit, remove the file.

At the next start, the process can see if the file exists, and if it does, it can read the file, and check for that process ID.